# Python pandas read_table whitespace delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I have this sample txt file that looks like:

```
ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD
ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST JOHNS
E000041196  25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP
```

etc...

What I need is this file to be loaded like:

```
 X  X.1 X.3 X.4 X.5
ACW00011604 17.1167 -61.7833    10.1    ST   JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD
ACW00011647 17.1333 -61.7833    19.2    ST JOHNS
```

I tried import pandas as pd

```
ds=pd.read_table("st.txt", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

but it works like:

```
X               X.1      X.3      X.4    X.5      X.6     X.7      X.8
ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST      JOHNS   COOLIDGE  FLD
ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST      JOHNS
E000041196   25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER.  AIRP
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) to read fixed width file formats and pass params `header=None` and your desired column names:

```
In [18]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD
ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST JOHNS
E000041196  25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP"""
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t), header=None, names=['X','X.1','X.3','X.4', 'X.5'])
df

Out[18]:
             X      X.1      X.3   X.4                    X.5
0  ACW00011604  17.1167 -61.7833  10.1  ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD
1  ACW00011647  17.1333 -61.7833  19.2               ST JOHNS
2   E000041196  25.3330  55.5170  34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP
```

So in your case the following should work:

```
ds=pd.read_fwf("st.txt", header=None, names=['X','X.1','X.3','X.4', 'X.5'])
```